# Resize a vertical split to just fit the max width of the file contents

Tags: neovim, vimscript-lua

I'm trying to make the width of a vertical split as small as possible but still fully show even the longest line of text. No line wrap.

I'm trying to do something like

```
:vertical resize <longest-text-line-length>
```

I also want to add such a command to a key-bindig in `init.lua`.

Comment: Did the solution solved your problem? How can we help you further? If it does maybe could you accept a solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allows the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```vim
function! GetMaxLength()
  let i = 1
  let maxlength = 0
  while i <= line('$')
    let l = len(getline(i))
    if l > maxlength
      let maxlength = l
    endif
    let i = i + 1
  endwhile

  echom 'length: ' . maxlength

  if &list
    let maxlength = maxlength + 1
  endif

  if &signcolumn !=# 'no'
    let maxlength = maxlength + 2
  endif

  if &number
    let maxlength = maxlength + max([&numberwidth, float2nr(log10(line('$'))) + 2])
  endif

  return maxlength
endfunction

function! SetMaxWidth()
  let maxlength = GetMaxLength()
  exe maxlength .. 'wincmd |'
endfunction
```

You can then call `SetMaxWidth()` like in the Vim command:

```vimscript
:call SetMaxWidth()
```

Or bind it to a key:

```lua
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>w', ':call SetMaxWidth()<CR>')
```

And here is a version in pure Lua:

```lua
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>w', function()
  i = 1
  maxlength = 0
  for i = 0, vim.api.nvim_buf_line_count(0) - 1 do
    l = string.len(vim.api.nvim_buf_get_lines(0, i, i + 1, 0)[1])
    if l > maxlength then
      maxlength = l
    end
    i = i + 1
  end

  if vim.o.list then
    maxlength = maxlength + 1
  end

  if not (vim.o.signcolumn == 'no') then
    maxlength = maxlength + 2
  end

  if vim.o.number then
    maxlength = maxlength + math.max(vim.o.numberwidth, math.floor(math.log10(vim.api.nvim_buf_line_count(0))) + 2)
  end

  vim.cmd(maxlength .. 'wincmd |')
end, { noremap = true })
```